# after success of ajax call: this page not working page error page in browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

after the success of the ajax call by clicking on the submit button I am getting the bellow error page in the browser and I can't find any errors in the console.

> **This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site
> owner. HTTP ERROR 405**

I am new to javascript, jquery, and ajax calls. So please give me suggestions for solving this error

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <div>
        <h1 class="myclass">HELLO!WELCOME</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <form id="loginform" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputphone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputpassword" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="forgot-password">
                <a href="">forgot password</a>
            </div>
             <button id="submit" class="submit-button" >Submit</button> 
           <!-- <input type="submit"value="Login"/>-->
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>    
</body></html>
```

JS code:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    alert(".click() called.");
    var inputphoneno = document.getElementById("inputphone").value;
    var inputpassword = document.getElementById("inputpassword").value;

    const jdata = {
        "phonenumber": inputphoneno,
        "password": inputpassword
    };

    try {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8085/Smatr/signIn",
            data: JSON.stringify(jdata),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            
               success: function (data) {
               console.log(data)
               alert(data);
         }   
           
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);

    }

});
```

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit process so your form is posting to the current page since no `action` exists. Your server is not allowing post to that endpoint thus you get a 405 error. Prevent the default submit so only the ajax request gets made

Comment: Also go look up  on web what various http status codes like 405 mean

Comment: ok thanks @charlietfl its working after adding the default prevent

Answer (score 0):

You should add attribute type="button" to prevent submitting form. If there is no attribute type, button behave like a submit button.

```
 <button id="submit" type="button" class="submit-button" >Submit</button>
```